# Failing import of zipped library with py-files

Tags: python, pyspark, pycharm, spark-submit

I have to maintain an oll code running with pyspark.
It's using a method I've never seen.
I have some reusable code zipped into a file ingestion.zip.
Then, this file is called using a pipeline.cfg file like this:

```
[spark]
master=spark://master
py-files=${HOME}/lib/ingestion.zip
spark-submit=${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit
```

When I'm trying to import the library as shown below, I cant make Pycharm understand that the lib should point to the zip file.

```
from ingestion.data import csv, storage
```

I've seen the zip is a solution proposed by spark-submit using py-files but how can I make it running on my IDE ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used below method with pycharm, but it worked for us with spark-submit and we could import these modules using normal import statements.
Actually, we had a very few files to import and we needed something quick. So, if you also have the same use-case and if pycharm allows then maybe, you can give it a try.

`--py-files s3://bucket-name/module1.py,s3://bucket-name/module2.py,s3://bucket-name/module3.py,s3://bucket-name/module4.py"`
(Note - there shouldn't be any spaces.)

(Note - this suggestion is only an interim solution till someone replies with a better answer.)